# Как правильно проинициализировать поля при вызове конструктора в конструкторе?

Tags: java, конструктор, инициализация, this

есть такой пример: Необходимо создать класс Human с полями возраст (age), имя (name), фамилия (secondName) и любимый вид спорта (favoriteSport).

Создайте 3 конструктора в классе Human, 1-ый - пустой, 2-ой, который конструирует Human’a от всех полей и третий, который конструирует Human’a, от всех полей, кроме любимого вида спорта. Для успешного тестирования решения важно объявлять аргументы в конструкторах именно в том порядке, в котором они написаны в данном описании (возраст (age), имя (name), фамилия (secondName) и любимый вид спорта (favoriteSport))

В методе main создайте 3 экземпляра человека используя 3 этих разных конструктора. поля класса должны иметь размерность, не превышающую необходимую. Класс должен быть объявлен статическим, метод main не должен находиться в классе, поля класса должны иметь доступ только внутри класса

Моя реализация:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human Kat = new Human();
        Human Olga = new Human((byte) 35, "Olga", "Ivanova");
        Human Kate = new Human((byte) 25, "Kate", "Petrova", "воллейбол");
    }

    public static class Human {
    private byte age; 
    private String name, secondName, favoriteSport;


    public Human() {

    }

    public Human(byte age, String name, String secondName) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

    public Human(byte age, String name, String secondName, String favoriteSport) {
        this (age, name, secondName);
        this.favoriteSport = favoriteSport;
    }
```

При вывозе методов у меня в консоль выводится (см картинка)

```
public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Привет, меня зовут " + name + "," + " мне " + age + " лет." + " " + "Моя фамилия" + " "
                + secondName + " "+ "спорт" + " " + favoriteSport);
    }


    public void sayHello1() {
        System.out.println("Привет, меня зовут " + name + "," + " мне " + age + " лет." + " " + "Моя фамилия"
                + " " + secondName);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: При вызове конструктора все поля должны быть инициализированы. Как это лучше сделать (на примере вызова конструктора в конструкторе)? Нужно ли вызывать super ()? И еще вопрос: что будет если вызвать конструктор с тремя параметрами?
Все ли поля инициализируются?  Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для разных типов создаются разные значения по умолчанию. 
Например для `int` по умолчанию `0`. 
Для `String` `null`.

При объявлении полей класса их можно проинициализирвать либо своими значениями по умолчанию, либо если ничего не делать - будут стандартные.

Super - это обращение к методу родителя, This - к текущему методу. В контструкторе лучше this использовать, что бы не дублировать логику.

```
public Human(String name, String secondName, int age, String sport) {
        this(name, secondName, age);
        this.sport = sport;
    }
```

Если вы при объявлении полей класса не проиничиализируете их какими то значениями, и потом в конструкторе тоже их не проиничиализируете, то они так будут хранить значения по умолчанию.

[Значения по умолчанию для примитивных типов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human h0 = new Human();
        Human h1 = new Human("Tom", "Henks", 56);
        Human h2 = new Human("Tom", "Henks", 56, "Running");

        System.out.println(h0 + "\n");
        System.out.println(h1 + "\n");
        System.out.println(h2);
    }
}

class Human {
    private final String defaultValue = "Empty";

    private int age;
    private String name = defaultValue;
    private String secondName = defaultValue;
    private String sport = defaultValue;

    public Human() {

    }

    public Human(String name, String secondName, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Human(String name, String secondName, int age, String sport) {
        this(name, secondName, age);
        this.sport = sport;
    }

    @Override

    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name +
                "\nSecondName: " + secondName +
                "\nAge: " + age +
                "\nSport: " + sport;
    }
}
```

В консоли будет :

```
Name: Empty
SecondName: Empty
Age: 0
Sport: Empty

Name: Tom
SecondName: Henks
Age: 56
Sport: Empty

Name: Tom
SecondName: Henks
Age: 56
Sport: Running
```

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 0):

В Kotlin для таких случаев используется конструкция `init()`, аналогично и здесь надо так же делать:

```
public Human(byte age, String name, String secondName) {
   init(age, name, secondName, null);
}

public Human(byte age, String name) {
   init(age, name, null, null);
}



private void init(byte age, String name, String secondName, String favoriteSport) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.secondName = secondName;
    this.favoriteSport = favoriteSport;
}
```

Таким образом достигается концентрация всех изменений в одном месте - в методе `init()`

Comment: У меня язык Java

Comment: вместо `private void init` пиши `private Human`

Comment: У меня вопрос был в другом, просьба пояснить с комментариями для чего это нужно

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Human human1 = new Human();
    Human human2 = new Human((byte)40, "Ivan",
            "Petrov","Streetball");
    Human human3 = new Human((byte)34, "Petr", "Ivanov");
    
}

public static class Human {
    public Human() {

    }

    public Human(byte age2, String name2, String secondName2, String favoriteSport2) {
        age = age2;
        name = name2;
        secondName = secondName2;
        favoriteSport = favoriteSport2;

    }

    public Human(byte age3, String name3, String secondName3) {
        this(age3, name3, secondName3, null);


    }

    byte age;
    String name;
    String secondName;
    String favoriteSport;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]